# Javascript error in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, xhtml

This error is only present in Internet explorer but works in Mozilla so far. Basically when someone selects an adtype on a drop down it should reveal the appropriate drop down. I will post the related code.

```
<script language="javascript">
    /* Hide and show appropriate drop down menu */
    var subs_array = new Array("pricefreq","pricetype"); // The id's of the hidden divs
    function displayOptions(the_sub){
        for (i=0;i<subs_array.length;i++){
            var my_sub = document.getElementById(subs_array[i]);
            my_sub.style.display = "none";
        }
        document.getElementById(the_sub).style.display = "inline-block";
    }


  </script>

                <select name="adtype" id="adtype" tabindex="1">
                    <option value="unselected">Please Select...</option>
                    <option value="to_buy" onmousedown="displayOptions('pricetype')">For Sale</option>
                    <option value="to_rent" onmousedown="displayOptions('pricefreq')">For Rent</option>
                </select>

                <select name="pricetype" id="pricetype" tabindex="8">
                    <option value="unselected">Please Select...</option>
                    <option value="Starting at">Starting At</option>
                    <option value="Fixed Price">Fixed Price</option>
                    <option value="Offers over">Offers Over</option>
                </select>

                <select name="pricefreq" id="pricefreq" tabindex="9">
                    <option value="unselected">Please Select...</option>
                    <option value="Per Week">Per Week</option>
                    <option value="Per Month">Per Month</option>
                    <option value="4 Weekly">4 Weekly</option>
                </select>
```

Comment: I say error, what i meant to say was that it doesnt do what its intended to do. So basically it does nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think mouse events work on option tags in IE.  You could apply an `onchange` event to the select element and feed the value `onchange="displayOptions(this.value)"` and then either translate the value in JS, or change the value of the option to ID that should show.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/dxhBs/1/

Comment: just an FYI, you probably want to set those additional select groups to none to begin with.

Comment: See: http://jsfiddle.net/dxhBs/2/ -- it takes away the unnecessary animation and only shows when it's required.  Prevents "noise" to viewers and prohibits users from making a premature selection.

Comment: Ah i get you, i already have that in my css i just didnt post it. thanks for your help anyways

Comment: You may also want to reset the values before setting it to none (set to `.defaultValue`).

Answer (score 0):

you can refactor your code as follow

```
var subs_array = new Array("pricefreq","pricetype"); // The id's of the hidden divs
function displayOptions(val){      
    if(val == 'unselected')
      return;  
    for (i=0;i<subs_array.length;i++){
        var my_sub = document.getElementById(subs_array[i]);
        my_sub.style.display = "none";
    }

    document.getElementById(val).style.display = "inline-block";
}
```

```
            <select name="adtype" id="adtype" tabindex="1" onchange="displayOptions(this.value);">
                <option value="unselected">Please Select...</option>
                <option value="pricetype" >For Sale</option>
                <option value="pricefreq" >For Rent</option>
            </select>

            <select name="pricetype" id="pricetype" tabindex="8">
                <option value="unselected">Please Select...</option>
                <option value="Starting at">Starting At</option>
                <option value="Fixed Price">Fixed Price</option>
                <option value="Offers over">Offers Over</option>
            </select>

            <select name="pricefreq" id="pricefreq" tabindex="9">
                <option value="unselected">Please Select...</option>
                <option value="Per Week">Per Week</option>
                <option value="Per Month">Per Month</option>
                <option value="4 Weekly">4 Weekly</option>
            </select>
```

Comment: This is one of the solutions I described.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your `onmousedown` on option tags and create an `onchange` on select tag:

```
<select name="adtype" id="adtype" tabindex="1" onchange="displayOptions(this.value)">
    <option value="unselected">Please Select...</option>
    <option value="to_buy">For Sale</option>
    <option value="to_rent">For Rent</option>
</select>
```

Then here's the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    /* Hide and show appropriate drop down menu */
    var subs = {"to_buy" : "pricetype", "to_rent" : "pricefreq"}; // The id's of the hidden divs
    function displayOptions(value) {
        for(sub in subs) {
            var my_sub = document.getElementById(subs[sub]);
            if(value == sub) my_sub.style.display = "inline-block";
            else my_sub.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
</script>
```